# how to normalize a numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, normalization, data-science

I have the following numpy array:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import numpy as np

# Tracking 4 associate metrics
# Open TA's, Open SR's, Open SE's
associateMetrics = np.array([[111,  28,  21],
   [ 27,  17,  20],
   [ 79,  23,  17],
   [185, 125,  50],
   [155,  76,  32],
   [ 82,  24,  17],
   [127,  63,  33],
   [193,  91,  63],
   [107,  24,  17]])
```

Now, I want to normalize every 'column' so that the values are between 0 and 1. What I mean is that the values in the 1st column for example should be between 0 and 1.

How do i do this?

```
normed_matrix = normalize(associateMetrics, axis=1, norm='l1')
```

the above gives me rowwise normalization

Comment: "will the above work?"  Did you try?

Comment: Do you want to divide each column by its maximum?

Comment: I think i have my answer.I tried putting axis=0 and it worked. the documentation wasn't clear for me i guess...http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this using the following:

```
normalized_metrics = normalize(associateMetrics, axis=0, norm='l1')
```

Comment: An axis in scipy specifies the dimension you are working on. For 2D data (matrxi), axis = 0 means across rows and axis = 1 means across columns. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/glossary.html

Comment: thank you! If I may ask an additional question. How would I multiply every column by different scalar values? What I want to do is assign different weights to each column. Should i do this after normalizaiotn? If yes, how? sorry I am a bit new to python

Comment: You can use numpy.multiply for element-wise multiplication of the weight vector by your matrix. Perhaps `np.multiply(v, m)` where `v` is your vector and `m` is your matrix.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html

Comment: Sorry, for column-wise multiplication you might need `np.multiply(v, m.transpose()).transpose()`